# CSS Following Siblings Selector

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

`~` is for the following sibling selector.

How could il select the class `.content` in reference to the class `.select` ?

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li> <a>content</a> </li>
  <li> <a class="select">selected li</a> </li>
  <li> <a>content</a> </li>
</ul>
<div class="content">
  selected content
<div>
```

CSS (not working)

```
ul > li > a.select ~ .content {
  /* something */
}
```

Comment: until CSS4 which has a parent selector - you can't

Comment: use jquery if you can.

Comment: but you could with javascript (note <div class=".content"> the . is not soo good)

Comment: @Danield: There is no parent selector. There is also no guarantee that the subject selector can be used in CSS. See my comments on the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector

Answer (score 1):

It's unfortunately not possible with CSS, but you could use JQuery, i.e. something like

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    $(".selected").parent().parent().siblings(".content").css("color", "red");
</script>
```

- *$(".selected")*   you start at 'a' tag
- *.parent()* move to parent 'li'
- *.parent()* move to parent 'ul'
- *.siblings(".content")* matches all siblings of the 'ul' you are currently at with class #content'
- *.css("color", "red")* do whatever fancy css you like ;)

Answer (score 0):

There's currently no way in CSS to select the class .content in reference to the class .select.

However if you change your markup a little you can do something similar to what you're trying to do using the `target` pseudo-class

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/9SxSA/7/)**

Comment: I'm working on ember.js and I have generated `.select` class. I've planned to use css only, but no way to do that in css3, thanks Danield

Comment: You may want to read over your own answer again. It's not pure CSS if you have to change the HTML to accommodate the CSS.